# Linux perf not resolving some symbols with high addresses starting with 0xffffffff

Tags: c++, perf

```
g++ -std=c++17 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O0 -g3 -o main main.cpp
perf stat ./main 5
perf report
```

```
  20.98%  main     [unknown]         [k] 0xffffffffb1077f22                                          ◆
  19.11%  main     main              [.] func                                                        ▒
  17.96%  main     libc-2.31.so      [.] __memset_avx2_erms                                          ▒
  13.07%  main     [unknown]         [k] 0xffffffffb067a936                                          ▒
   5.75%  main     [unknown]         [k] 0xffffffffb10e68e5                                          ▒
   3.30%  main     main              [.] std::min<int>                                               ▒
   1.72%  main     [unknown]         [k] 0xffffffffb1077f25                                          ▒
   1.58%  main     [unknown]         [k] 0xffffffffb086f485                                          ▒
   1.01%  main     main              [.] std::max<int>
```

`func` is a symbol in main.cpp, so symbols in my source file have been resolved. I call `std::max` and `memset`, they have beed resolved, too. But what about `0xffffffffb1077f22`, it is an address. And with `nm main`, I'm sure that it is not a symbol in main source file. What is it? I don't think it is a library function because `memset` and `std::max` can be resolved.

I run perf in ubuntu virtual machine of macos.

Comment: Probably the standard library's start-up function that gets invoked before `main` to do various setup like initialisation of static globals and whatnot that needs to happen before `main`. Also, even at `-O0 -g3` not everything is guaranteed to have debug symbols. Also, not all system libraries are guaranteed to have debug symbols.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Those are kernel addresses; they have their high bit set.  (In fact they're in the high 32 bits of virtual address space.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not give attention to the warning message of `perf report`.
It says:

```
WARNING: Kernel address maps (/proc/{kallsyms,modules}) are restricted,
check /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict and /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid.
```

So it seemed that I should set a proper value in /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict.

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict
```

Then the address can be resolved.